# Best CAD system for Mac

Tags: software-recommendation, software

I need a 3D CAD system for Mac, but as I am student now, I haven't got the opportunity to buy AutoCAD. So, can you recommend some good 3D CAD software on Mac? I found one - Autodesk Inventor, but when I saw that it is "Free" I don't believe it, as it is Autodesk, or it is really free?

Comment: With the requirements you've listed, I'd start with any free package and return with some objective criteria that define what "best" means in particular to you. We have a guide at [help] that will assist you in getting the best help here by showing your research and perhaps listing why you feel you need the software. Focusing on describing your details of the task you are seeking to solve with this software package will help us help you.

Comment: This is not an answer as bmike is correct that you need to first define your needs - data compatibility - training sessions online, input devices and output formats. That being said, the three that I've tried are TurboCad, ArchiCad, and Cadintosh. The last one is made by the same (great) people who make Graphic Converter, and is only about $25.

Comment: How will you use it?  Architectural packages are different than part modeling, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

AutoCAD for Mac is free for students, along with several other Autodesk apps. Software Downloads Software license terms are for 3 years.

> [image]
>
> ## Education Community
>
> ### Free Software for Students in the Education Community
>
> More than 35 software products are available for free* download from the Education Community—each with a 36-month license. Start the academic year off right by downloading the 2013 Autodesk® software that professional architects, engineers, and digital artists use to push the boundaries of design. You want to change the world. We want to help you do it.

See [Autodesk Education Community - Free Software for Students](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/item?siteID=123112&id=14185424)